# Dynamic Jackson Custom Deserializer

Tags: java, jackson

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"typeName":"test","field":{"name":"42"}}
```

I have two deserializers. The first one (`JsonDeserializer<EntityImpl>`) will examine the JSON and extract a type information which is provided by the `typeName` property.

The second deserializer (`JsonDeserializer<TestField>`) is used to deserialize the `field` property. This deserializer **needs to know** the previously extracted `typeName` value in order to work correctly.

How can i pass-along the type information from one deserializer to other deserializers? I tried to use DeserializationContext but i don't know how to pass along the Context from deserializer A to B.

My current code looks like this:

EntityImpl.java:

```
package de.jotschi.test;

public class EntityImpl implements Entity {

    private String typeName;

    private TestField field;

    public String getTypeName() {
        return typeName;
    }

    public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }

    public TestField getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(TestField field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

TestField.java:

```
package de.jotschi.test;

public class TestField {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
package de.jotschi.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.InjectableValues;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import de.jotschi.test.EntityImpl;
import de.jotschi.test.TestField;

public class TestMapper2 {

    private InjectableValues getInjectableValue() {

        InjectableValues values = new InjectableValues() {

            @Override
            public Object findInjectableValue(Object valueId, DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty forProperty, Object beanInstance) {
                if ("data".equals(valueId.toString())) {
                    return new HashMap<String, String>();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        return values;

    }

    @Test
    public void testMapper() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule idAsRefModule = new SimpleModule("ID-to-ref", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

        idAsRefModule.addDeserializer(EntityImpl.class, new JsonDeserializer<EntityImpl>() {
            @Override
            public EntityImpl deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

                Map<String, String> dataMap = (Map) ctxt.findInjectableValue("data", null, null);
                System.out.println("Value: " + dataMap.get("test"));

                ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
                JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jp);
                String type = node.get("typeName").asText();
                dataMap.put("typeName", type);

                // How to pass on type information to TestField deserializer? The context is not reused for the next deserializer.
                // I assume that readValueAs fails since the codec.readTree method has already been invoked.
                //return jp.readValueAs(EntityImpl.class);

                // Alternatively the treeToValue method can be invoked in combination with the node. Unfortunately all information about the DeserializationContext is lost. I assume new context will be created.
                // How to reuse the old context?
                return codec.treeToValue(node, EntityImpl.class);

            }
        });

        idAsRefModule.addDeserializer(TestField.class, new JsonDeserializer<TestField>() {
            @Override
            public TestField deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                // Access type from context
                Map<String, String> dataMap = (Map) ctxt.findInjectableValue("data", null, null);
                System.out.println(dataMap.get("typeName"));
                ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
                JsonNode node = codec.readTree(p);
                return codec.treeToValue(node, TestField.class);
            }

        });

        mapper.registerModule(idAsRefModule);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        // Setup the pojo
        EntityImpl impl = new EntityImpl();
        impl.setTypeName("test");
        TestField testField = new TestField();
        testField.setName("42");
        impl.setField(testField);

        // POJO -> JSON
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(impl);
        System.out.println(json);

        // JSON -> POJO
        Entity obj = mapper.reader(getInjectableValue()).forType(EntityImpl.class).readValue(json);
        System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());

    }

}
```

Comment: This type information manual handling is reinventing a wheel. Jackson can already do that. See this article http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html

Comment: My type information is not referring to a class. The type information is basically used to dynamically build the POJO manually within the TestField derserializer. I'm therefore not able to use the types system of jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is call the following mapper this way:

```
        return mapper.setInjectableValues(getInjectableValue(dataMap)).treeToValue(obj, EntityImpl.class);
```

This way the previously loaded context data map is put into a new context that is used for the following parsing process.

Full example:

```
package de.jotschi.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.InjectableValues;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class TestMapper2 {

    private InjectableValues getInjectableValue(final Map<String, String> dataMap) {

        InjectableValues values = new InjectableValues() {

            @Override
            public Object findInjectableValue(Object valueId, DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty forProperty, Object beanInstance) {
                if ("data".equals(valueId.toString())) {
                    return dataMap;
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        return values;

    }

    @Test
    public void testMapper() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule idAsRefModule = new SimpleModule("ID-to-ref", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

        idAsRefModule.addDeserializer(Entity.class, new JsonDeserializer<Entity>() {
            @Override
            public Entity deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

                Map<String, String> dataMap = (Map) ctxt.findInjectableValue("data", null, null);
                ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
                ObjectNode obj = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jp);
                String type = obj.get("typeName").asText();
                dataMap.put("typeName", type);
                return mapper.setInjectableValues(getInjectableValue(dataMap)).treeToValue(obj, EntityImpl.class);
            }
        });

        idAsRefModule.addDeserializer(TestField.class, new JsonDeserializer<TestField>() {
            @Override
            public TestField deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                // Access type from context
                Map<String, String> dataMap = (Map) ctxt.findInjectableValue("data", null, null);
                System.out.println("Type name: " + dataMap.get("typeName"));

                ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
                ObjectNode obj = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(p);

                // Custom deserialisation
                TestField field = new TestField();
                field.setName(obj.get("name").asText());
                // Delegate further deserialisation to other mapper
                field.setSubField(mapper.setInjectableValues(getInjectableValue(dataMap)).treeToValue(obj.get("subField"), SubField.class));
                return field;
            }
        });

        mapper.registerModule(idAsRefModule);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        // Setup the pojo
        EntityImpl impl = new EntityImpl();
        impl.setTypeName("test");
        TestField testField = new TestField();
        testField.setName("42");
        SubField subField = new SubField();
        subField.setName("sub");
        testField.setSubField(subField);
        impl.setField(testField);

        // POJO -> JSON
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(impl);
        System.out.println(json);

        // JSON -> POJO
        Entity obj = mapper.reader(getInjectableValue(new HashMap<String, String>())).forType(Entity.class).readValue(json);
        assertNotNull("The enity must not be null", obj);
        assertNotNull(((EntityImpl) obj).getField());
        assertEquals("42", ((EntityImpl) obj).getField().getName());
        assertNotNull(((EntityImpl) obj).getField().getSubField());
        assertEquals("sub", ((EntityImpl) obj).getField().getSubField().getName());
        System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());

    }

}
```